# Combos dinámicos dependientes en AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot

Tengo 2 combos realizados independientemente, cada uno tiene su controller y service, ambos ya muestran la data correspondiente, pero la idea es que sean dependientes.

Tenemos la entidad Area y Cargo. Cargo debe ser dependiente de Area.

```
<div class=" col-sm-2" ng-app="nep" ng-controller="AreaController as ar">
    <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="ar.selectedArea" required="required" >
        <option>--Seleccione--</option>
        <option ng-repeat="a in ar.areas " value="{{a.ncodAreaPk}}">{{a.cnomArea}}</option>
    </select>

</div>


<div class="col-sm-3" ng-app="nep" ng-controller="CargoController as cargoemp">
    <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="cargoemp.selectedCargo" required="required" >
        <option>--Seleccione--</option>
        <option ng-repeat="a in cargoemp.cargos " value="{{a.ncodCargoPk}}">{{a.cnomCargo}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: por que no haces un controller con ambos?

Comment: por separado no se puede manejar?, es necesario que esten ambos juntos? y cual seria el metodo?

Comment: Pueden estar por separado, podés usar un servicio para comunicarte, pero hay una necesidad real de que estén en dos controladores separados?

Comment: en caso fuese asi cual seria el metodo que enlazaria ambos combos

Comment: Podría ser algo así: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wl9Lda9hULSxMy2kJjvM?p=preview, en caso de que sea lo que estás buscando, armo una explicación en una respuesta

Comment: ponle un ng-change para que cuando cambien un combo el otro tambien se rellene pero asegurate de vaciar el arreglo antes de eso saludos